# php-server setup not working

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php

I have installed php and apache2 server before but I'm getting bogged down with errors.

The process so far is as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install tasknet
sudo apt-get install lamp-server
```

During the installation, tasksel stops with

```
tasksel: aptitude failed (100)
```

I tried:

```
sudo tasksel remove lamp-server
sudo apt-get install lamp-server
```

With the same error

Next I tried

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

with the following result:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.13.04.1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up php5-common (5.4.9-4ubuntu2.1) ...
Not replacing deleted config file /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo.ini
ERROR: /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo.ini does not exist
dpkg: error processing php5-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-cli:
 php5-cli depends on php5-common (= 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing php5-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php5:
 libapache2-mod-php5 depends on php5-common (= 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-mysql:
 php5-mysql depends on phpapi-20100525; however:
  Package phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5filter which provides phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
  Package php5-cli which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
 php5-mysql depends on php5-common (= 5.4.9-4ubuntuNo apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
2.1); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing php5-mysql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 php5-common
 php5-cli
 libapache2-mod-php5
 php5-mysql
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I tried:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and got the following:

```
Setting up php5-common (5.4.9-4ubuntu2.1) ...
Not replacing deleted config file /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo.ini
ERROR: /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo.ini does not exist
dpkg: error processing php5-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.13.04.1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-cli:
 php5-cli depends on php5-common (= 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing php5-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php5:
 libapache2-mod-php5 depends on php5-common (= 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-mysql:
 php5-mysql depends on phpapi-20100525; however:
  Package phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5filter which provides phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
  Package php5-cli which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
 php5-mysql depends on php5-common (= 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing php5-mysql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5-common
 mysql-server-5.5
 php5-cli
 libapache2-mod-php5
 mysql-server
 php5-mysql
```

After looking through these errors, I tried installing mySQL server again manually with

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```

but got the same errors as I recieved in the last set of errors.

I ran

```
 sudo tasksel --test
```

with the following result:

```
debconf-apt-progress -- apt-get -q -y install lamp-server^
```

so I ran this command with `sudo` and at 15% it said installing mysql-server then on to mysql-com at 18% where it stopped.

Ran through a few of the commands I had already tried with the same results.

## The Question.

Please can you advise what I should do next?

## UPDATE

I entered `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and after downloading and checking the packages the following report was given:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.13.04.1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
```

etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using lamp-server and tasksel, I recommend people to install apache and mysql the normal way, which is how they are usually setup on servers.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server php5-mysql
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This is compatible with how many other packages that are installed. For instance, you can do

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

and browse it on `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`

Comment: should I run `sudo tasksel remove lamp-server` and `sudo apt-get purge tasksel` first?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to remove these before trying my method.

Comment: Just done that and get the same results. How do I completely remove everything I have tried to install over the past couple of days? as I think that previous attempts may have blocked further installations :(

Comment: Try apt-get with the `purge` option. `sudo apt-get remove --purge tasknet`

Comment: After doing this for each of the packages, I'm going to try your answer again...

Comment: Back to the drawing board. still getting the same errors... any further thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I used to do:

```
$ sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

Rather than using `apt-get` - that always worked for me. However, I recommend installing as per Capt.Nemo's instructions.